# Type expected and can not find name 'Record' and can not find name 'undefined'

Tags: npm-install, typescript-eslint

I started getting these error after intalling jquery,popper and bootstrap packages into the project. Error is in index.d.ts file and to resolve error checked various refrence and asked to update typescript version.

i have installed npm because earlier runing upgrade command in nuget pm console was getting an error 'npm' not found hence npm installed then run command npm install -g npm@9.6.2
[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCkyi.jpg). Also tried to select typescript version manually by doing right click on project ->properties->typescript build but here typecript version dropdown is not coming this is the snapshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrgGT.jpg). Can someone help with how to resolve this error

Answer (score 1):

These errors type expected, can not found name Record, undefined comes after installing popper.js package.popper.js is javascript file which has dependency over typescript file which is index.d.ts. To resolve this error i tried to install popper.js typescript file from nuget package manager window. Right click on project node and click on manage nuget package manager and from there install popper.js typescript and install then in project directory inside src folder typescript folder created and it has popper.d.ts file. Now install popper.js from nuget package manager and you will see index.d.ts would have generated in folder which contains all the popper.js files. Still the error is same. Copy entire code of popper.d.ts and paste it in index.d.ts so basically you replacing the index.d.ts code with popper.d.ts . Now rebuild the project and the error gone.